# Русификация Date-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Как сделать русификацию календаря?

```
 $(function() {
    $('#date-picker').daterangepicker({
        "opens": "left",
        singleDatePicker: true,
        isInvalidDate: function(date) {
        var disabled_start = moment('09/02/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        var disabled_end = moment('09/06/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
        return date.isAfter(disabled_start) && date.isBefore(disabled_end);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Эмм.. а что вы тут хотите русифицировать, покажите

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/681211